# Python: Convert Unicode-Hex-String to Unicode

Tags: python, unicode, hex

I have a hex-string made from a unicode string with that function:

```
def toHex(s):
    res = ""
    for c in s:
        res += "%02X" % ord(c) #at least 2 hex digits, can be more
    return res

hex_str = toHex(u"...")
```

This returns a string like this one:

```
"80547CFB4EBA5DF15B585728"
```

That's a sequence of 6 chinese symbols.
But

```
u"Knödel"
```

converts to

```
"4B6EF664656C"
```

What I need now is a function to convert this back to the original unicode. The chinese symbols seem to have a 2-byte representation while the second example has 1-byte representations for all characters. So I can't just use unichr() for each 1- or 2-byte block.

I've already tried

```
binascii.unhexlify(hex_str)
```

but this seems to convert byte-by-byte and returns a string, not unicode. I've also tried

```
binascii.unhexlify(hex_str).decode(...)
```

with different formats. Never got the original unicode string.

Thank you a lot in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to work just fine:

```
binascii.unhexlify(binascii.hexlify(u"Knödel".encode('utf-8'))).decode('utf-8')
```

Comes back to the original object. You can do the same for the chinese text if it's encoded properly, however `ord(x)` already destroys the text you started from. You'll need to encode it first and only then treat like a string of bytes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! My problem is, that I get the Hex-String from a 3rd party software and thus I have no influence to the encoding...

Comment: Ask them what encoding is it then. Otherwise, you won't be able to decode it correctly...

Comment: Also, it seems the text might be utf-16. `binascii.unhexlify("80547CFB4EBA5DF15B585728").decode('utf-16')` seems to return something asian (can't verify what though)

Comment: Thanks alot! It really seems to be UTF-16 with Big Endian byte order!

    `(codecs.BOM_UTF16_BE + binascii.unhexlify("80547CFB4EBA5DF15B585728")).decode('utf-16')`


seems to do the right thing.
Thanks again for all your answers!

Answer (score 1):

Can't be done. Using `%02X` loses too much information. You should be using something like UTF-8 first and converting that, instead of inventing a broken encoding.

```
>>> u"Knödel".encode('utf-8').encode('hex')
'4b6ec3b664656c'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! My problem is, that I get the Hex-String from a 3rd party software and thus I have no influence to the encoding...
So you mean, that there is no way to surely reconstruct what "80547CFB4EBA5DF15B585728" means?

Comment: That is correct. Unless you agree on a consistent protocol, which brute-force encoding as the code gives is not.

Comment: @Robert:  if it's made with a known encoding, you can get the text e.g. UTF-8 or UTF-16.

Answer (score 0):

When I was working with Unicode in a VB app a while ago the first 1 or 2 digits would be removed if they were a "0". Meaning "&H00A2" would automatically be converted to "&HA2", I just created a small function to check the length of the string and if it was less than 4 chars add the missing 0's. I'm not sure if this is what's happening to you, but I thought I would give bit of information as something to be aware of.