# Python 3 - String with \xHH Hex Values to Unicode

Tags: python-3.x, hex, unicode-string, unicode-escapes

I am trying to convert a string with characters that require multiple hex values like this:

```
'Mahou Shoujo Madoka\xe2\x98\x85Magica'
```

to its unicode representation:

```
'Mahou Shoujo Madoka★Magica'
```

When I print the string, it tries to evaluate each hex value separately, so by default I get this:

```
x = 'Mahou Shoujo Madoka\xe2\x98\x85Magica'
print(x)

Mahou Shoujo MadokaâMagica
```

so I have tried some other StackOverflow answers, such as [Best way to convert string to bytes in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585435/best-way-to-convert-string-to-bytes-in-python-3):

```
x = 'Mahou Shoujo Madoka\xe2\x98\x85Magica'
z = x.encode('utf-8')
print('z:', z)
y = z.decode('utf-8')
print('y:', y)

z: b'Mahou Shoujo Madoka\xc3\xa2\xc2\x98\xc2\x85Magica'
y: Mahou Shoujo MadokaâMagica
```

[Python: Convert Unicode-Hex-String to Unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6773270/python-convert-unicode-hex-string-to-unicode):

```
z = 'Mahou Shoujo Madoka\xe2\x98\x85Magica'
x = binascii.unhexlify(binascii.hexlify(z.encode('utf-8'))).decode('utf-8')
print('x:', x)

x: Mahou Shoujo MadokaâMagica
```

And some others, but none of them worked. Most of the results I found were people who had a [double backslash problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33257875/python-string-to-bytes-conversion-double-backslash-issue), but none of them had my exact problem.

What I notice is that when I do str.encode, it seems to add some extra values into the binary (such as the difference between z and x in the first attempt), and I'm not quite sure why.

So I tried manually typing in the characters of the string into the binary:

```
x = b'Mahou Shoujo Madoka\xe2\x98\x85Magica'
x.decode('utf-8')

'Mahou Shoujo Madoka★Magica'
```

and it worked. But I couldn't find a way to convert from a string to a binary literally other than typing it out. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Python 3 your original string is a Unicode string, but contains Unicode code points that look like UTF-8, but decoded incorrectly.  To fix it:

```
>>> s = 'Mahou Shoujo Madoka\xe2\x98\x85Magica'
>>> type(s)
<class 'str'>
>>> s.encode('latin1')
b'Mahou Shoujo Madoka\xe2\x98\x85Magica'
>>> s.encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
'Mahou Shoujo Madoka★Magica'
```

The `latin1` encoding happens to map 1:1 to the first 256 code points in Unicode, so `.encode('latin1')` translates the code points directly back to bytes.  Then you can `.decode('utf8')` the bytes properly.

Comment: To assign a string to a variable, you can shorten the above to `s = b"\xe2\x98\x85".decode("utf8")` as well.

Comment: @Jens you could shorten it to `s='★'` but that wasn't the point of the question.